# При приближение зума карты кластеры (метки) не отображаються на Яндекс Map Kit (android Kotlin)?

Tags: yandexmapkit, mapkit

Требуеться реализовать корректное отображение меток на карте.

Реализовал отображение меток. Но при приближения зума метки одна за другой пропадают с экрана. Т.е. непонятно на какой объект и куда ссылается метка.

[image: Самый большой зум]  [image: Приближаю карту]  [image: и здесь уже нет меток]

```
class TextImageProvider(private val text: String, private val context: Context) : ImageProvider() {
        private val FONT_SIZE = 15f
        private val MARGIN_SIZE = 3f
        private val STROKE_SIZE = 3f
        override fun getId(): String {
            return "text_$text"
        }

        override fun getImage(): Bitmap {
            val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
            val manager: WindowManager = getSystemService(context, WindowManager::class.java) as WindowManager
            manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)
            val textPaint = Paint()
            textPaint.setTextSize(FONT_SIZE * metrics.density)
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)
            textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)
            textPaint.setAntiAlias(true)
            val widthF: Float = textPaint.measureText(text)
            val textMetrics: Paint.FontMetrics = textPaint.getFontMetrics()
            val heightF: Float = Math.abs(textMetrics.bottom) + Math.abs(textMetrics.top)
            val textRadius =
                Math.sqrt((widthF * widthF + heightF * heightF).toDouble()).toFloat() / 2
            val internalRadius: Float = textRadius + MARGIN_SIZE * metrics.density
            val externalRadius: Float = internalRadius + STROKE_SIZE * metrics.density
            val width = (2 * externalRadius + 0.5).toInt()
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            val backgroundPaint = Paint()
            backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true)
            backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE)
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, width / 2f, externalRadius, backgroundPaint)
            backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE)
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, width / 2f, internalRadius, backgroundPaint)
            canvas.drawText(
                text,
                width / 2f,
                width / 2 - (textMetrics.ascent + textMetrics.descent) / 2,
                textPaint
            )
            return bitmap
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentPickUpBinding.bind(view)

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())

        fragmentBinding = binding
        fragmentBinding.apply {
            initViews()
            initObservable()
            mapYandex.map.move(
                CameraPosition(TARGET_LOCATION, 17.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 5f),
                null
            )
            val imageProvider: ImageProvider = ImageProvider.fromResource(
                context, R.drawable.ic_maps_pin_cluster
            )
            val collectionCluster: ClusterizedPlacemarkCollection =
                mapYandex.map.mapObjects.addClusterizedPlacemarkCollection(this@PickUpFragment)
            val places = TempDataGenerator.getPoint()
            collectionCluster.addPlacemarks(places, imageProvider, IconStyle()
                .setAnchor(PointF(0.5F, 05f))
                .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                .setZIndex(1f)
                .setScale(0.5f)
            )
            collectionCluster.clusterPlacemarks(50.0, 15)

        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onClusterAdded(cluster: Cluster) {
        cluster.appearance.setIcon(
            TextImageProvider(cluster.size.toString(), requireContext())
        )
        cluster.addClusterTapListener(this)
    }
```

```
    override fun onClusterTap(cluster: Cluster): Boolean {
        requireContext().toast("Нажал на кластер")
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите ваш код. На данный момент сложно понять причину вашей 
проблемы.

Comment: Поправил, код взят по примеру с данного гита от яндекса https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/tree/vbazhenov/add_clustering/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo